# Aspnet core, identity server and react : how to retrieve access token as claim from external provider

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, identityserver4

This is with regards to aspnet core 3.0 and react template introduced in Vs 2019 which hosts an identity server 4.

As I'm new to identity server and aspnet core I might not doing the right way.

The problem is "I want to retrieve access token as a part of claim on client side (react app) acquired by signing in using an external provider like Google."

I followed this article:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/additional-claims?view=aspnetcore-3.1

However I still cannot see the access token from Google in browsers local storage. I can however see the access token from identity server and other additional claims for example users display name.

Comment: why do you need token from google ?

Comment: Your google's ID token will decode by Identity Server 4 , IDS will issue it's own token and return to your client (react) app , what is your scenario to use token from google ?